# Rspec double returning NoMethodError

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

Not sure if my syntax is right, it doesn't seem to recognise the stub I've passed to my double.

```
class Robot
  def boogie friend
    friend.dances
  end
end
```

Test:

```
describe Robot do

let(:robo_friend){double(:friend, {dances: true})}

  it "should have a friend dance too" do
    expect(subject.boogie :robo_friend).to be true
  end

end
```

And the error:

```
Robot should have a friend dance too
 Failure/Error: expect(subject.boogie :robo_friend).to be true
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `dances' for :robo_friend:Symbol
 # ./lib/robot.rb:3:in `boogie'
 # ./spec/robot_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `allow(robo_friend).to receive(:dances).and_return(true)` https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-3/docs/configuring-responses/returning-a-value

Comment: I need to use it outside the 'it' block, so it can be used for multiple other tests. I think let is the right way to do this but can't get it to work.

Comment: change `expect(subject.boogie :robo_friend).to be true` to `expect(subject.boogie robo_friend).to be true` `robo_friend` is injected into your let as a method, so you shouldn't use the symbol https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-5/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work, you need to pass the object and not a symbol.

```
describe Robot do
  let(:robo_friend) { double("Friend", dances: true) }

  it "should have a friend dance too" do
    expect(subject.boogie(robo_friend).to eq(true)
  end
end
```